# Right way to handle this situation using Laravel validation

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-validation

i am new in Laravel and I would like to have some directive on how to handle this situation.

I have two entities: Ad and Nomination. Ad can have many Nominations.

In a controller i receive two external inputs: [ad_id] and [nomination_id] both required.

What i have to do with these two inputs is:

- Check if [ad_id] is an existing Ad entity and his attribute "active" is true.
- Check [nomination_id] is an existing Nomination entity.
- Only if [ad_id] was an existing Ad and [nomination_id] was an existing Nomination check if this Nomination belongs to this Ad.

Can you show me an example about how to manage this using only validation class?

Comment: Didn't see last line. My answer shows it in controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your validation rules like this

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'ad_id' => [
            'bail',
            'required',
            Rule::exists('ads')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where([
                    ['active' => 1],
                    ['id' => $request->ad_id]
                ]);
            }),
        ],
        'nomination_id' => [
            'bail',
            'required',
            Rule::exists('nominations')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where([
                    ['ad_id' => $request->ad_id],
                    ['id' => $request->nomination_id]
                ]);
            }),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Assuming you have `ads` and `nominations` are tables name and primary key field is `id` and `ad_id` as foreign key in nominations table.

Comment: plusOne. Maybe just nomination_id rule be sufficient in case?

Comment: in question it mention that field should be check required for both before other validation.

Comment: This way separate messages are supported. Good answer.

Comment: Using `Rule` helper for such trivial validation is redundant IMO. 18 lines of code instead of 2. Answer is correct anyway.

Comment: Where is the part in which you specify that check on nomination ownership have to be performed ONLY id [ad_id] and [nomination_id] result as existing entities?

Comment: What really i want prevent is check ownership of nomination if both ad and nomination are not existing entities

Comment: check validation on `nomination_id`, that validate `nomination_id` belongs to `ad_id`

Comment: yes but i want this happen only if check on ad_id not fail

Comment: @topogigio then you can add `bail` validation. updated answer check it

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward - you can write validation rules just as you listed them in your question:

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->only('ad_id', 'nomination_id'), [
    'ad_id' => 'required|exists:ads,id,active,1',
    'nomination_id' => 'required|exists:nominations,id,ad_id,' . $request->ad_id,
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this check if id and ad_id belong to the same row?

Comment: @Tpojka what `id` do you mean? We have `ad_id` and `nomination_id` in the question. We are not provided with any info about the row that holds those foreign key columns.

Comment: I mean second line in validator. Does it check if ad_id belongs to right row where nomination_id has been found or just check existence of ad_id in any row of nominations table?

Comment: @Tpojka it checks existence of said nomination by it's `id` and `ad_id` columns. We are not provided with any information regarding the row wtih those foreign key columns. To validate it (lets say we have `id` of this row and it's table is `rows`) we would need separate rule: `'id' => 'required|exists:rows,id,ad_id,' . $request->ad_id . ',nomination_id,' . $request->nomination_id`. It depends on the context of the situation whether or not we possess that info and need to validate it as well.

Comment: Something like that. `'nomination_id' => 'required|exists:nominations,id,ad_id,' . $request->ad_id` seems should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$inputAd = <some_value>;
$inputNomination = <some_value>;

$nomination = Nomination::where(['id' => $inputNomination])->with(['ads'])->first();

if(!$nomination || !($nomination->ad_id == $inputAd)) {
    // not the same
}

// same
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @JensHabegger Correct. Actually, this is not right choice since I wrote it before checked OP wants validator solution. Code is meant to be in controller preferably.

Answer (score 0):

To validate the `ad_id` and `nomination_id`, you can use laravel `in` rule.

**FormRequest Class**

```
public function rules()
{

    return [
        'ad_id'         =>  [
                                'required',
                                Rule::in(Ad::where('active', true)->pluck('id')->toArray()),
                            ],
        'nomination_id' =>  [
                                'required',
                                Rule::in(Nomination::where('id', $this->nomination_id)->where('ad_id', $this->ad_id)->pluck('id')->toArray()),
                            ],
    ];
}
```

The `Rule::in(Ad::where('active', true)->pluck('id')->toArray()),` rule will check if the `ad_id` is present in the array of ids of `Ad` which have `active` field is `true`.

The `Rule::in(Nomination::where('id', $this->nomination_id)->where('ad_id', $this->ad_id)->pluck('id')->toArray()),` rule will check if the `nomination_id` is present in the array of ids of `Nomination` which is related to `Ad`.